# Ubuntu 19.10 on VirtualBox icon overlapping

Tags: icons, 19.10

[image: Image showing columns of icons overlapping in the Application screen]
If scrolling app list, only 19.10 this problem will occur, no problem with other versions

Answer (score 1):

Yep, the VMSVGA is the cause (default graphics controller on VirtualBox 6.0), tried switching to VBoxSVGA and it stops glitching. 18.04 has no problem with any 3 of those graphics controllers.

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/softwaregore/comments/dje3dw/i_give_ubuntu_1910_a_shot_on_virtualbox_and_apps/)